# Image not positioned correctly in a Canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

As you can see here: https://codepen.io/Le-future/pen/gKNoEE

I have a slight problem with the images as they are not centered in the circles, is someone could help?

```
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(object.x, object.y, object.size/1.25, 0,2*Math.PI);
    ctx.fillStyle = object.couleur;
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.restore();

    ctx.drawImage(object.image, object.x, object.y, object.size, object.size);
```

Answer (score 1):

Change: `ctx.drawImage(object.image, object.x, object.y, object.size, object.size);`

To this: `ctx.drawImage(object.image, object.x-object.size/2, object.y-object.size/2, object.size, object.size);`

**Why?** You're not taking the width and height of the object into account to center it. The *x* and *y* positions are located in the top left of the object, so subtracting those points by 1/2 of its width and height centers it.

Comment: Ah you have been more fast than me! I just thought about that after my post, thanks a lot for the great answer :-)